# Menu drop-down tabs of certain apps won't open

Tags: bug-reporting

I'm not entirely sure why, but when I open something like Wireshark or a PDF-viewer application that I downloaded, when I click on the menus at the top (e.g. the "file" menu which would open top to the "open" "recent" etc. options) those suboptions don't open. This also happens on buttons like the "+" button in OBS Studio.

The buttons stay lit up in blue, so they acknowledge that they've been clicked, and they become deselected once I click them a second time, but nothing appears under them. . .

The apps still work as far as the main part of the window is concerned, but they're not of much use when I can't access the "open PDF file" options of my PDF viewer and can't do any analysis with my wireless capture analysis app lol.

I don't even know what could have caused something like this? I've uninstalled and re-installed the apps in different ways multiple times.

Also the edit-post feature won't let me change the tag it changed from "ubuntu-bug" to "bug-reporting" so if a mod could change that instead of smiting me with holy rage because the site thought it knew what I wanted and changed something for me, that'd be cool.